# sqlite vs shared memory app vs ipc vs?

Tags: sqlite, ipc, shared-memory, named-pipes

I'm not even sure of the right terminology, so let me start with my objective: to have a simple app ("Data Doler") that does nothing but read a huge hunk of data from a file into memory, and then serve up slices of that data to a single multi-threaded app called "Data Lapper", or to multiple instances of Data Lapper.

Data Doler only needs to start up and read the data hunk once, and so I want it to stick around at least until Armageddon.  Data Doler should just sit there idling, waiting for Data Lapper(s) to connect and start requesting data. Data Doler will always run on a multi-core machine with > 50 gigabytes of memory.

The data is static and read only, and it is indexed such that all Data Lapper needs to do is give Data Doler a memory address and it instantly gets back the exact slice of data requested.

Data Doler can be written in any language (C, C++, AtariBasic, etc).

I have the C source code for Data Lapper, so how I connect to Data Doler is entirely open.

I've started to educate myself about SqLite, shared memory apps, named pipes, ipc, etc.  But I'm hoping someone can save me some time by telling me which tree I should be barking up, or whether I'm so clueless about this stuff I'd be better off staying on the porch.

Comment: Is it high read or write?  Do the reads contend?  How long does the doler hold onto data?

Comment: Why don't you just let the Data Lappers read the file directly, and let the OS's file cache take care of the rest? And which OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be some simpler solutions than rolling your own depending on throughput and how long the data sticks around.

Something like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) would really svelt if it fit your requirements.  It is in use all over the web.

If you are hand-crafting a code solution, you might consider [boost interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html).  It is pretty reasonable for IPC.